# Qt3DCore simple wireframe viewer

Tags: python, viewer, pyside6, wireframe

I'm learning PySide6, and my goal is to use Qt3DCore to draw some 3D wireframe entities (points, lines, bezier curves ..uso..), in a 3D viewer. I like that high level interface.

I used the nice basic torus sphere example (https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_3d__simple3d.html) of the documentation, and added some QLineF lines, but I don't see the lines in the viewer scene.
I think it's because I don't have the correct graphics setting for such wireframe entities... But I don't find any other example or documentation on the subject :-(.

As requested by musicamante, to be as simple as possible, I add the QT example with only 2 modifications : QLine import, and QLine statement in line 121 :

```
"""PySide6 port of the qt3d/simple-cpp example from Qt v5.x"""

import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import (Property, QObject, QPropertyAnimation, Signal,QPoint,QLine,QLineF)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QGuiApplication, QMatrix4x4, QQuaternion, QVector3D)
from PySide6.Qt3DCore import (Qt3DCore)
from PySide6.Qt3DExtras import (Qt3DExtras)
from PySide6.Qt3DRender import (Qt3DRender)

       
class OrbitTransformController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._target = None
        self._matrix = QMatrix4x4()
        self._radius = 1
        self._angle = 0

    def setTarget(self, t):
        self._target = t

    def getTarget(self):
        return self._target

    def setRadius(self, radius):
        if self._radius != radius:
            self._radius = radius
            self.updateMatrix()
            self.radiusChanged.emit()

    def getRadius(self):
        return self._radius

    def setAngle(self, angle):
        if self._angle != angle:
            self._angle = angle
            self.updateMatrix()
            self.angleChanged.emit()

    def getAngle(self):
        return self._angle

    def updateMatrix(self):
        self._matrix.setToIdentity()
        self._matrix.rotate(self._angle, QVector3D(0, 1, 0))
        self._matrix.translate(self._radius, 0, 0)
        if self._target is not None:
            self._target.setMatrix(self._matrix)

    angleChanged = Signal()
    radiusChanged = Signal()
    angle = Property(float, getAngle, setAngle, notify=angleChanged)
    radius = Property(float, getRadius, setRadius, notify=radiusChanged)


class Window(Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Camera
        self.camera().lens().setPerspectiveProjection(45, 16 / 9, 0.1, 1000)
        self.camera().setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 40))
        self.camera().setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0))

        # For camera controls
        self.createScene()
        self.camController = Qt3DExtras.QOrbitCameraController(self.rootEntity)
        self.camController.setLinearSpeed(50)
        self.camController.setLookSpeed(180)
        self.camController.setCamera(self.camera())

        self.setRootEntity(self.rootEntity)

    def createScene(self):
        # Root entity
        self.rootEntity = Qt3DCore.QEntity()

        # Material
        self.material = Qt3DExtras.QPhongMaterial(self.rootEntity)

        # Torus
        self.torusEntity = Qt3DCore.QEntity(self.rootEntity)
        self.torusMesh = Qt3DExtras.QTorusMesh()
        self.torusMesh.setRadius(5)
        self.torusMesh.setMinorRadius(1)
        self.torusMesh.setRings(100)
        self.torusMesh.setSlices(20)
        

        self.torusTransform = Qt3DCore.QTransform()
        self.torusTransform.setScale3D(QVector3D(1.5, 1, 0.5))
        self.torusTransform.setRotation(QQuaternion.fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1, 0, 0), 45))

        self.torusEntity.addComponent(self.torusMesh)
        self.torusEntity.addComponent(self.torusTransform)
        self.torusEntity.addComponent(self.material)

        # Sphere
        self.sphereEntity = Qt3DCore.QEntity(self.rootEntity)
        self.sphereMesh = Qt3DExtras.QSphereMesh()
        self.sphereMesh.setRadius(3)

        self.sphereTransform = Qt3DCore.QTransform()
        self.controller = OrbitTransformController(self.sphereTransform)
        self.controller.setTarget(self.sphereTransform)
        self.controller.setRadius(20)

        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self.sphereTransform)
        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation.setTargetObject(self.controller)
        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation.setPropertyName(b"angle")
        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation.setStartValue(0)
        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation.setEndValue(360)
        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation.setDuration(10000)
        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation.setLoopCount(-1)
        self.sphereRotateTransformAnimation.start()

        self.sphereEntity.addComponent(self.sphereMesh)
        self.sphereEntity.addComponent(self.sphereTransform)
        self.sphereEntity.addComponent(self.material)

        self.lineEntity = QLineF(-2000.0, -2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Window()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec
```

())

Comment: Sorry but we don't provide links to tutorials or examples. If your code doesn't do what you expect, then provide a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I included the Qt example program, and only 2 modifications. I don't see the drawn line at screen.

Comment: Did you check out the Qt3D wireframe example? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-example.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with C++, and I don't find that example sources in Python. I installed Qt Creator ( Qt 6.2.3 mingw), but I even don't see that example in the C++ examples. May be I should install Qt Creator with Qt3D using a specific option ? PS : It seems I have to download Qt and Qt3D sources, then recompile everything, and that people had a lot of problems trying that :-(

Comment: Qt3D sources are on github,  I'll try to port that example to python.

Comment: I think the essential part is the shaders of the example. The rest probably takes some time to port to Python if you're inexperienced with C++ but you'll manage :)

Comment: May be :-)  I had a look and it's not easy for me, due to the C++, but also the QML which is not the same in C++ and Python..
Since several years, I look for an example with 3D wireframe display, trackball pan, zoom and raycasting picking. In any type of framework, python binded, using glfw, wx, Qt, pyglet,pygame ...etc.. and I never founded any working  example !